Insert multiple rows in ORACLE by referring 2 tables
I have 2 tables with data as below
Table 1: ProductTransaction
Product Id | TransactionId
1          | 90
1          | 91 
2          | 91 
2          | 93 

Table 2: ProductEnrollment
Product Id | EnrollmentId
1          | 31
1          | 32 
2          | 41 
2          | 43 

I have a new table called ProductEnrollmentTransaction and I have to insert rows by referring Table 1 and 2. First, get the Product Id from Table 2 then get TransactionId from table 1 and then insert into table 3. For an instance, Enrollment 31 and 32 are associated with Product Id 1 and Product Id is associated with TransactionId 90 and 91. So New table must have transactionId and EnrollmentId based on product Id mapping.
TransactionId | EnrollmentId
90             | 31 
91             | 31
90             | 32 
91             | 32
91             | 41
93             | 41
91             | 43
93             | 43

How to write an Insert query in Oracle (19C) by referring to 2 tables? This query must go to all the way to Production. Please help us.

What probalem are you actually facing? Looks like a common inner join to me. Is it the general syntax for an insert select you are looking for?

@ThorstenKettner. It worked with inner join. Thank you

Use INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... and INNER JOIN the two tables:
INSERT INTO ProductEnrollmentTransaction (TransactionId, EnrollmentId)
SELECT t.TransactionId,
       e.EnrollmentId
FROM   ProductTransaction t
       INNER JOIN ProductEnrollment e
       ON (t.ProductID = e.ProductID)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE ProductTransaction (ProductId, TransactionId) AS
SELECT 1, 90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 91 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 91 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 93 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE ProductEnrollment (ProductId, EnrollmentId) AS
SELECT 1, 31 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 32 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 41 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 43 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE ProductEnrollmentTransaction (
  TransactionId NUMBER,
  EnrollmentId  NUMBER
);

Then, after the INSERT, the table contains:



TRANSACTIONID
ENROLLMENTID




90
31


91
31


90
32


91
32


91
41


93
41


91
43


93
43



fiddle
